# Angular 2 @angular2-material npm library

Tags: angular, npm, angular-material

Using MdTabModule , before the md-tab-group i m using a form and keeping the submit button after the /md-tab-group and keeping disabled until all the fields are filled, but the moment i fill the data on tab1 the button gets enabled ,so could anyone help me y is that happening so , the same works fine when I have the form all in a single page.

`<form class="my_form" #data1="ngForm (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(data1.value)">`

```
    <md-tab-group>




        <md-tab>
            <template md-tab-label>1</template>
            <template md-tab-content>
               <input type=text required>
                <input type=text required>
                 <input type=text required> 
                 <input type=text required>
                  <input type=text required>
                   <input type=text required>


            </template>
        </md-tab>

       <md-tab>
            <template md-tab-label>2</template>
            <template md-tab-content>
               <input type=text required>
                <input type=text required>
                 <input type=text required> 
                 <input type=text required>
                  <input type=text required>
                   <input type=text required>


            </template>
        </md-tab>

        <md-tab>
            <template md-tab-label>2</template>
            <template md-tab-content>
               <input type=text required>
                <input type=text required>
                 <input type=text required> 
                 <input type=text required>
                  <input type=text required>
                   <input type=text required>


            </template>
        </md-tab>


    </md-tab-group>

    <button type="submit" class="my_button btn btn-success" 
          [disabled]="!data1.valid">  submit</button>




</form>
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you should use @angular/material rather than @angular2-material. See here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/material

Comment: @PeterSalomonsen but will that really solve my problem????

Comment: for me the problem is that the form tag is loosing the scope after that md-tab gets closed , so how could i overcome it??

Comment: @AyzPat you need to check if formcontrol is Dirty for Every field or if the From group is valid then enable the Button , i guess that will do the trick for you, and also enclose the md-tab under a group

Comment: @AyzPat It worth a try to update to @angular/material since the version you are using is a very old Alpha. There were some significant changes in the Tab components which may have impact on the problems you're experiencing.

Comment: @PeterSalomonsen I will do it and update u of the working..

Comment: @AyzPat i feel that the form should be inside the md-tab as each tab will have its own data right and then you can check if all the forms are valid you enable the button

Comment: @RahulSingh cn u plz get an dummy plunker of the same? with some dummy forms??I am using template forms..

Comment: @PeterSalomonsen grt working after using the angular/material

Comment: @PeterSalomonsen now using autocomplete in that getting error as in this issue  https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3176  while using in my app ..